# dropdown box selection size

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to have a fixed heigh in the listing (selection) of dropdown box?

Dropdown Box
--select 1
--select 2
--select 3
--select 4.. and so on.

At some point the scroll bar will appers. How do I do in order to have prevent it?

I would like to show all of the listing in the dropdown box.

Answer (score 0):

Only with jquery form plugins, alone with CSS it's impossible

Comment: Well, without a JavaScript work-around. jQuery isn't the only way to accomplish this. I personally like http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ .